# Does adding lemon juice to water chemically alter its nutrients and thereby negating any of its health benefits?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, food-chemistry

An acquaintance who apparently has some chemistry understanding told me that eating lemon juice freshly squeezed to drinking water negates all of its health benefits because the water chemically alters the vitamins minerals and enzymes. I am very dubious because a lemon is 82% water and a human body is 75% water and of course lemon juice must be to a very great extent just water. 
Also lemon juice is renowned as being a great morning drink because of its health benefits.
My acquaintance however emphatically stands by his statement.
Please clarify this situation for me.
Does water really chemically alter the nutrients in lemon juice rendering a lemon drink of no health benefit whatsoever other than the obvious water base?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: It seems this guy is making a fool of you, only thing I can think of is oxidating wit. C by chlorine in water.

Comment: This question is suitable for [skeptics.se] or [health.se]

Answer (score 5):

> Does water really chemically alter the nutrients in lemon juice rendering a lemon drink of no health benefit whatsoever other than the obvious water base?

No, of course not. Otherwise, humanity would have succumbed to scurvy a long time ago.

I encourage you and your friend to visit [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) where you can peruse hundreds of refereed abstracts of studies that illustrate that nutrients from citrus fruits are bioavailable to humans and other species and necessarily require administration with water.

[Here](http://health.clevelandclinic.org/2015/06/7-reasons-to-start-your-day-with-lemon-water-infographic/) is a one-pager on lemon juice from the Cleveland Clinic, which is probably a reliable enough source in this case if you want to skip the more technical items at PubMed.